# app engine custom domain not working

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, g-suite, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine with Google Apps. I can access my site through   http://mydomain.appspot.com. I've been setting it up with a custom domain using http://aralbalkan.com/1466

I registered my domain with GoDaddy and set pointed the nameservers to dyndns. Within dyndns I've created a CNAME to ghs.google.com and verified it using

http://www.mxtoolbox.com/

I've set up the A records to 216.239.32.21, 216.239.34.21, 216.239.36.21, and 216.239.38.21 and verified them using the above tool.

I've added the domain inside Appengine to www.mydomain.com and linked it to my apps account. The traceroute for www.mydomain.com ends up at  74.125.47.121 (a google web site) does anyone have any idea why this could be failing. I'm only trying to link to the www.mydomain.com site not the naked domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is the right setup - it just takes a while for the DNS to propogate it seems.